# How do you get the GMSMarker with the highest zIndex for didBeginDraggingMarker

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm using Google maps iOS SDK v1.8 and trying to perform marker dragging on a set of markers in close proximity.  The zIndex is working as I expected for visuals but not for behaviours.

Consider a group of markers on top of each other with different zIndexes:

```
for (int i = 0; i <5; i++) {
    GMSMarker *test = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:location];
    test.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test %i", i];
    test.draggable = YES;
    test.zIndex = 100 - i;
    test.map = mapView;
}
```

In the delegate I have

```
-(void) mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didBeginDraggingMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker {
    NSLog(@"didBeginDraggingMarker: %@ (%i)", marker.title, marker.zIndex);
}
```

I expected this to drag the marker `Test 0` at zIndex 100 but instead it drags `Test 2` at zIndex 98.  The order it selects them seems random. For example if I drag each marker out of the way this is my log.

```
didBeginDraggingMarker: Test 2 (96)
didBeginDraggingMarker: Test 0 (100)
didBeginDraggingMarker: Test 1 (99)
didBeginDraggingMarker: Test 3 (97)
didBeginDraggingMarker: Test 4 (96)
```

So my question is how do I force the selection of the marker with the highest zIndex when dragging?

I've considered Iterating through the entire collection of markers isn't ideal due to the large number of markers.

Comment: Im having the same issue and I tried the same way of assigning incremental/decremental z index for each marker. Only that Im looking for click events instead of dragging but the click event is received for a random marker if there are multiple ones on top of each other. Did you get a solution for this? Thanks.

Comment: @Abu Unfortunately not  (and yes, this random order apply's to all the events).  You can work around this for a tap event by iterating over your collection of markers and using the one with the highest z-Index that is within a certain screen distance of the tap event.  Basically, search for the marker manually